# How do I insert source code into a Pages document on Mac?

Tags: c#

I have been working on a source code file in Visual Studio for Mac, the bulk of which now needs to be effectively copy-and-pasted into a Pages document. Cmd+A -> Cmd+C -> Cmd+V looks terrible and requires lots of formatting. Is there a less clunky way to insert code snippets into Pages such that readability is prioritised? Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like more of a word processing usage problem than a programming problem.  Historically word processors are for creating documents, not IDE-formatted source code.  (They also have a habit of replacing quotes with stylized quotes and other ways of destroying the usability of the actual code.  Not to mention the tons of spelling/grammar flags that would litter the code in a word processor.)  In general it comes down to a choice between meticulously re-formatting the code in the word processor or using screenshots/images of code in the document.

Comment: I guess screenshots are my best bet then. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to copy code from Android Studio (highlight, then Cmd + C) and paste it directly into Pages, at the cursor (Cmd + V) and retain the exact styling, including font, text color and background.

Here's a screenshot of the pasted code in Pages:

[image: screenshot of code pasted into pages]

It also worked with code copied directly from StackOverflow, VS Code, Sublime text 2, and Brackets, though text colors & background colors didn't always transfer.

I'm using Pages version 10.1 (6913) on a 2019 iMac with Mojave (10.14.6)

Answer (score 0):

What you can try doing is you can copy the code you want from let's say visual studio code. Once you have it copied, go to google docs, paste it, and change the background to full black and do some changes with the font. Copy your thing, and then paste it in pages............!

Answer (score 0):

You could try, after pasting the code, clicking on the text which is on the right side, which may show as 'default' change that to the body. You can transfer it to to an actual font. clear and discoloured font is your final result.